# cap "no such file or directory /usr/bin/env npm" although it is really here

Tags: npm, capistrano

I'm having this weird `cap` error when running the task returns :

```
INFO[f0017d58] Running /usr/bin/env npm install --silent on default
DEBUG[f0017d58] Command: cd /var/www/myapp/releases/20141208112620 && /usr/bin/env npm       install --silent
DEBUG[f0017d58]     /usr/bin/env:
DEBUG[f0017d58]     npm
DEBUG[f0017d58]     : No such file or directory
DEBUG[f0017d58]
cap aborted!
```

Where this works just fine (with the same user) when i'm logged in through `ssh` :

```
vagrant@localhost:~$ cd /var/www/myapp/releases/20141208112620 && /usr/bin/env npm    install --silent
grunt-contrib-uglify@0.3.3 node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify
├── grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1 (zlib-browserify@0.0.1)
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
└── uglify-js@2.4.15 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, optimist@0.3.7, source-map@0.1.34)
```

So there's something weird that i can't identify.

Thanks for your help.

---

*Edit*: so yeah, I found out the origin of the actual issue.
When I log-in (via `vagrant ssh`) I get a different env than the one I get with `cap`.
Basically I can call `npm` from CLI when logged in and this will find it in `/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/npm`, while `cap` can't, since none of this is in the path it's using (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Below fixe took care of the problem

## deploy.rb

```
set :nvm_node, 'v8.9.1'

set :nvm_map_bins, %w{node npm}
```

## Gemfile

```
gem 'capistrano-nvm'
```

## Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/nvm'
```